# Problema usando iframes

Tags: iframe, dominio

A la atención de quien corresponda.

Contexto: Estamos realizando una herramienta enfocada al neuromarketing que es capaz de trackear la mirada del usuario, leer sus emociones y en base a estos resultados generar datos estadísticos que ayuden a la toma de decisiones.

La herramienta se llama Neurocatching y puede ser utilizada para el estudio de imágenes, videos y webs. Cuando el conductor del experimento da un estudio de alta, éste lo comparte mediante una url a todos los sujetos candidatos de ser estudiados.

Descripción del problema:

Algunas de las webs que se utilizan para el estudio como:

https://www.diariodeteruel.es/

O

https://www.thefork.com/

No pueden ser incluidas para el estudio.

La manera en la que incluimos elementos como páginas web en nuestra plataforma para que luego puedan ser objetos de estudio es mediante un componente iframe como el siguiente:
[image: Contenido iframe]

Sin embargo, este método funciona para algunos sitios web y para otros no, como los mencionados anteriormente. En los casos en los que no se puede acceder a la página web obtenemos un resultado como el siguiente:
[image: Resultado no acceso]

A nivel de consola obtenemos el siguiente error:
[image: Consola error]

Según hemos indagado errores de este tipo de deben a permisos de dominios, es decir que solo las páginas que estén hospedadas en el mismo dominio pueden usar el iframe de la misma manera que pretendemos, en el mejor de los casos.

Una alternativa que hemos pensado para subsanar este problema es evitar el iframe y hacer que la página web que queremos usar para el estudio de cargue en una pestaña del navegador y no en la misma página del estudio, evitando así, el uso del iframe. No obstante, esta solución pese a que si nos deja acceder a todas las páginas que deseamos produce otro problema. Existe una pestaña inicial donde inicia el estudio, una pestaña en la que se efectúan todas las operaciones de carga e inicialización de elementos para captar emociones del estudio de manera que cuando se pierde el foco de esta pestaña, como por ejemplo cuando saltamos a una web, se detiene todo.

Esto provoca que el usuario sí que pueda navegar por la web que nosotros como experimentadores queremos que haga, pero que los medios y recursos para captar información como clicks, emociones, etc se detengan ya que están en otro lado.

En conclusión, si usamos iframes podemos recolectar todos los datos que queremos, pero no podemos acceder a todas las webs.

Si usamos pestañas en vez de incrustar la web, la experiencia de usuario es mejor, se puede acceder a todos las webs, pero la recogida de datos se empeora.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida. Gracias!!!